# unable to display result through foreach loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have array its name is $img_arr and it shows following records. I want to display images with its relevant ids. so I have the following array. but unable to implement it.

```
Array(
[0] 1
[1] 2
[2] 3
[3] 4
)
Array(
[0] adsense-approval.png
[1] feedback.jpg
[2] logo1.jpg
[3] logo2.png
)
```

my code is following. in id and data-id i want to get array result 0,1,2..

```
<?php 
    if(isset($img_arr) && !empty($img_arr)){ 
        foreach($img_arr as $img){ ?>

    <div class="img-wrap" id="img_<?php echo $img;?>">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="./gallery/<?php echo $img ?>" class="img-circle" style="height:50px; width:50px;" data-id="<?php echo $img ?>">
    </div>
<?php 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Use key in your foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way with your `HTML` code:

```
$idArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$imageArray = array('adsense-approval.png', 'feedback.jpg', 'logo1.jpg', 'logo2.png');

foreach($idArray as $key => $value) 
{
    echo $value;
    echo $imageArray[$key];
}
?>
```

If we merge code with your `HTML` it looks as follow

```
<?php 
    if(is_array($imageArray))
    { 
        foreach($imageArray as $key => $img)
        { ?>
            <div class="img-wrap" id="img_<?php echo $img;?>">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <img src="./gallery/<?php echo $img ?>" class="img-circle" style="height:50px; width:50px;" data-id="<?php echo $idArray[$key] ?>">
            </div>
<?php 
    } 
}
?>
```

Basically, you need to manage your image with your `Id array` in the key-value format for that you need to use the `$key` variable in you `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` can be used with only values or with key value pairs.

**Only Values:**

```
foreach ($array as $value) { // Where $value is array value
...
```

**Key Value Pairs:**

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { // Where $key -> key & $value -> value
...
```

You need to add `key` in `foreach`'s definition.

**Working Code:**

```
<?php if(isset($img_arr) && !empty($img_arr)){ 
                  foreach($img_arr as $key => $img){ ?>
                <div class="img-wrap" id="img_<?php echo $key;?>">
                     <span class="close">&times;</span>
                            <?php echo $key;?> <img src="./gallery/<?php echo $img ?>" class="img-circle" style="height:50px; width:50px;" data-id="<?php echo $key ?>">
                        </div>
                  <?php } }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image path is wrong, You must write "../gallery" instead of "./gallery".

```
<?php 
    if(isset($img_arr) && !empty($img_arr)){ 
        foreach($img_arr as $img){ ?>

    <div class="img-wrap" id="img_<?php echo $img;?>">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="../gallery/<?php echo $img ?>" class="img-circle" style="height:50px; width:50px;" data-id="<?php echo $img ?>">
    </div>
<?php 
    } 
}
?>
```